# cant display text in mvc pdfsharp project need to remove tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, tags, plaintext

i have this line of code in my mvc 4 pdfsharp project and i cant seem to figure out how to get the decsription field to display just the text when the pdf is generated. all my other lines display fine an they are all set up the same, it is just this one I cant figure out:

graphics.DrawString("" + report.Description, font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(margin, page.Height - (lineHeight * 35), page.Width, page.Height), XStringFormats.TopCenter);
 currentTop += lineHeight;

this is what the pdf displays from that line: Normal;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;color: #000000;">Incident API

this is what it should display: Incident API

does anyone know what I can add to this line of code to make it display properly. any advice or support would be greatly appeciated. if you need more info please ask. i have been stuck on this forever and cant seem to figure it out.

thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a simple regex and just display plain text and no tags in the pdf report. Here is the code if anyone else has the same problem:

```
  report.Description = Regex.Replace(report.Description, "<.*?>|&nbsp;", string.Empty);
```